# Does JPA support getting data from Database Views?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, netbeans, mssql-jdbc

Basically in our project, We are using Eclipse Connected with MySQL Database. Now am using JPA as ORM Tool. Later we moved to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 for Database. I don't have access to Tables in MSSQL-2008. I have access only to [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) in MSSQL-2008. I would like to Know

1. It is possible to get Data from Database  [View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) with JPA?

I want to get data from View and show it to the user using POJO class. That is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. JPA Supports getting Data from Database view. **It is possible to create Entity Class from Database view**, But the problem is, **every column from database view is treated as Object  Class by JPA.(You will get Object as return type in getter method for each column).**  If needed we can change those column database types to corresponding data types. It works for me. **But double check with your Senior Developer to proceed with Database view in JPA.**

Answer (score -1):

In eclipse, setup database connection in by doing:

- Create JPA Project:
  File > New > Other > JPA > JPA Project, Next
          JPA details and click Finish
- Create Connection profile to database:
  In JPA prespective, create a connection by right clicking on Database Connections and enter driver info etc. Connect to database from eclipse
- In Generate Entities From Tables
  Choose JPA Project > JPA Tools > "Generate Entities From Tables" and select the tables that you need.

Comment: I understand that i can generate JPA Entity Class from Any of table. But i would like to know that, is there any options available to generate JPA Entity Class from View available in DB.